# Field Missing / Field Not Showing Process Builder Create a Record

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, process-builder, field-update, create-records

I am trying to create a record via Process Builder, and set the value for a custom field of type text, but the custom field doesn't show up in the list of fields that I can set. How can I get this field to show up in the "set field values" list?

[image]

Comment: Check the field visibility first and remember if you added the field after you started the PB session you need to exit it and go back into Process Builder for it to be visible.

Comment: You also need edit access on that field for it to show up, I would think.

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked field-level security when I initially created the field. Making the field visible first did the trick.